# How to redirect a user back to where he was after login in asp.net mvc 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC3 and I'm now examining the user handling.
My first problem would be (I know there is a lot about this subject in other threads, I just fail to find a good one with MVC3) that I want the login page to redirect me where I came from, or where I was redirected from.
In php perhaps I would add this url to the querystring, maybe.
But I need a way to do this somehow automatically, and this is a so common design pattern I was wondering if there is a "built in" way to do this.

What would be the cleanest, or preferred way to do this?

Also when I'm redirecting to a login page which would be the best way for checking and storing the url which I'm redirected from? I would check for the referrer in the request object and spit it out in the url as "?redirect=protected.html" but I'm not even sure how to properly do this.

Any advice on this subject would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MVC works the same way as ASP.NET.

If you use Forms Authentication a lot of those questions will be answered for you.

In your Web Config find the line that says `authentication="Windows"` and then change that to `Forms`

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" />
</authentication>
```

MVC 3 will actually give you the Account/LogOn route as part of the MVC 3 template project (check your models and see if you have one called `AccountModel`).

Then you just add `Authorization` to deny all users to your site:

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

by default this will send any person coming to your site off to your login.

So after you have validated that there login credentials are correct you set the `AuthCookie` the same as ASP.NET:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userName, false);
```

Form this you can the redirect to where ever you want.

to redirect back to where you came from use:

```
FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(userName, false);
```

Not forgetting the other useful statement of:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

Without Authentication the site wont let you access anywhere until you are logged in, so the CSS will stop working.

The locations I have added to make sure this doesnt happen are as follows:

```
<location path="Content">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
<location path="Scripts">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?"/>
  </authorization>
 </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: Note to new come, this is detailed info and consider intermediate level. You can allow/deny based on location (directory allow/deny in Apache .htaccess) This example best to use at private/corporate web site since it deny all at first except css/images/js folder and not necessarily happened in most cases.

Answer (score 3):

In asp.net it is a ?returnUrl=...

(1) Make sure you have something like

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

in your root web.config.

(2) In your Controller you want to protect, add `[Authorize]` attribute above it.

Please create new project and select the **Internet Application** template rather than **Empty** one and you will get sample of the simple login process as well as changing password.

Note: Please read this as well: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/preventing-open-redirection-attacks

The sample shows after logging in process, it make sure the returnUrl is a local url by the Url.IsLocalUrl() helper to protect from Open Redirection Attack.

**Update:**
The best way is to implement your own **custom login process** after you really know the standard process for example instead of using the URL to track where the user come from, you can set a new cookie to store the returnUrl with [httponly cookie](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533046%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and delete it just before redirect to previous page.

Another common practice is to **use roles**. You may specific a directory/controller for specific group of user called `Role` by adding the permitted role like this as an attribute above the controller:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
```

See [this](http://www.dotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/mahesh/ASPNetConfuguration05072005030817AM/ASPNetConfuguration.aspx) visual studio **administration tool** to create sample users and roles with **built-in** web interface.

You may also want to **use sitemap** to arrange your pages and menu link with **show/hide menu** based on current user role. Use this [mvcsitemap](http://mvcsitemap.codeplex.com/) to add **security trimming** features in ASP.NET MVC sitemap.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases there happens to be a custom authentication instead of standard forms based (common case for enterprise level applications).

In this case I would recommend manually managing `returnUrl` parameter in the querystring. Login page reads this URL and redirects back after successful authentication.